# "Стрелять" и "стрелы"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему стрел уже давно нет, а глагол всё тот же? Существует ли какой-то адекватный синоним?

Comment: Существует: **пулять**. См. Большой толковый словарь: 
**ПУЛЯТЬ**, -яю, -яешь; нсв. 1. чем. Разг.-сниж. Бросать чем-л. в кого-л. или куда-л. П. камнями, снежками. 2. **Стрелять**. П. из рогатки по воробьям. Кончай п.!  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: И это: **палить**. **ПАЛИТЬ**, -лю, -лишь; нсв. Разг. 1. **Стрелять из пушек, ружей и т.п.** (обычно залпами). П. из автомата. П. со всех сторон. П. по зайцам. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о стрелах, то употребляется глагол "пускать". Говорят: "пускать стрелы", "пустить стрелу", а также "выпустить стрелу".

Употребляется также глагол "бить". Как правило (но не всегда), он обозначает работу одиночными выстрелами, причём чаще в разговорной речи: "он неплохо бьёт из мелкашки"  = "он метко стреляет из мелкокалиберной винтовки".  С некой натяжкой можно использовать слово "бить" и для работы очередями (и тоже скорее в разговорной речи): "он засел в развалинах и бил из автомата по набегавшим духам". Оборот "бьёт без промаха", изначально просторечный, стал настолько распространённым , что с какого-то момента вошёл и в литературную речь. Вполне литературным является оборот "бьёт зверя". (Здесь "бьёт" выступает синонимом глагола "стреляет" с оттенком "добывает".)

Очень просторечным является употребление глагола "лупит". Причём, этот глагол скорее применим к стрельбе очередями.